Arduino Cloud Editor not detecting the Ardiuno board
I've been programming my Arduino Uno R3 just fine, but when I updated to the new editor (I took a long break), it doesn't detect my board.  I've looked around in a bunch of places for a solution but can't find any.
I'm on a Macbook Pro, M1, and I've tried this both with Firefox and Safari.
In System Info, in the USB tab, the Arduino board (connected through a USB hub to accommodate the non-C type USB plug) shows up.  The lights on the board also do turn on.

